Modified Android SDK number in Gradle from 24 to 31 and now all Gradle compile is broken
My project was compiling & executing fine.
I wanted to change the min SDK from 24 to 31.
I did the change in the Gradle build file.
Now when I recompiled Gradle, all is broken with the many errors below result
I have no idea about the problem. I just know java
/home/gilles/android-studio/jbr/bin/java -javaagent:/home/gilles/android-studio/lib/idea_rt.jar=40415:/home/gilles/android-studio/bin -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath /home/gilles/android-studio/plugins/Kotlin/kotlinc/lib/kotlin-compiler.jar:/home/gilles/.gradle/caches/8.6/generated-gradle-jars/gradle-api-8.6.jar:/home/gilles/.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-8.6-bin/afr5mpiioh2wthjmwnkmdsd5w/gradle-8.6/lib/groovy-3.0.17.jar:/home/gilles/.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-8.6-bin/afr5mpiioh2wthjmwnkmdsd5w/gradle-8.6/lib/groovy-ant-3.0.17.jar:/home/gilles/.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-8.6-bin/afr5mpiioh2wthjmwnkmdsd5w/gradle-8.6/lib/groovy-astbuilder-3.0.17.jar:/home/gilles/.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-8.6-bin/afr5mpiioh2wthjmwnkmdsd5w/gradle-8.6/lib/groovy-console-3.0.17.jar:/home/gilles/.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-8.6-bin/afr5mpiioh2wthjmwnkmdsd5w/gradle-8.6/lib/groovy-datetime-3.0.17.jar:/home/gilles/.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-8.6-bin/afr5mpiioh2wthjmwnkmdsd5w/gradle-8.6/lib/groovy-dateutil-3.0.17.jar:/home/gilles/.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-8.6-bin/afr5mpiioh2wthjmwnkmdsd5w/gradle-8.6/lib/groovy-groovydoc-3.0.17.jar:/home/gilles/.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-8.6-bin/afr5mpiioh2wthjmwnkmdsd5w/gradle-8.6/lib/groovy-json-3.0.17.jar:/home/gilles/.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-8.6-bin/afr5mpiioh2wthjmwnkmdsd5w/gradle-8.6/lib/groovy-nio-3.0.17.jar:/home/gilles/.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-8.6-bin/afr5mpiioh2wthjmwnkmdsd5w/gradle-8.6/lib/groovy-sql-3.0.17.jar:/home/gilles/.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-8.6-bin/afr5mpiioh2wthjmwnkmdsd5w/gradle-8.6/lib/groovy-templates-3.0.17.jar:/home/gilles/.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-8.6-bin/afr5mpiioh2wthjmwnkmdsd5w/gradle-8.6/lib/groovy-test-3.0.17.jar:/home/gilles/.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-8.6-bin/afr5mpiioh2wthjmwnkmdsd5w/gradle-8.6/lib/groovy-xml-3.0.17.jar:/home/gilles/.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-8.6-bin/afr5mpiioh2wthjmwnkmdsd5w/gradle-8.6/lib/javaparser-core-3.17.0.jar:/home/gilles/.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-8.6-bin/afr5mpiioh2wthjmwnkmdsd5w/gradle-8.6/lib/kotlin-stdlib-1.9.20.jar:/home/gilles/.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-8.6-bin/afr5mpiioh2wthjmwnkmdsd5w/gradle-8.6/lib/kotlin-reflect-1.9.20.jar:/home/gilles/.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-8.6-bin/afr5mpiioh2wthjmwnkmdsd5w/gradle-8.6/lib/gradle-installation-beacon-8.6.jar:/home/gilles/.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-8.6-bin/afr5mpiioh2wthjmwnkmdsd5w/gradle-8.6/lib/gradle-kotlin-dsl-extensions-8.6.jar:/home/gilles/.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-8.6-bin/afr5mpiioh2wthjmwnkmdsd5w/gradle-8.6/lib/gradle-kotlin-dsl-8.6.jar:/home/gilles/.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-8.6-bin/afr5mpiioh2wthjmwnkmdsd5w/gradle-8.6/lib/gradle-kotlin-dsl-shared-runtime-8.6.jar:/home/gilles/.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-8.6-bin/afr5mpiioh2wthjmwnkmdsd5w/gradle-8.6/lib/gradle-kotlin-dsl-tooling-models-8.6.jar:/home/gilles/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.android.tools.build/gradle/8.4.0/bdb2cec5d8f62c2d4689d860c6e5de1eb7ac9fa3/gradle-8.4.0.jar:/home/gilles/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.android.tools.build/gradle-settings-api/8.4.0/2e95d4817e1a2982dd77123fccc76ff257674ad0/gradle-settings-api-8.4.0.jar:/home/gilles/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.android.tools.lint/lint-model/31.4.0/9e5a5fdecfe4f1a457e00009441232089cce237f/lint-model-31.4.0.jar:/home/gilles/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.android.tools.build/builder/8.4.0/8aaa522e739c616e216e211d0b82c4c05ed08397/builder-8.4.0.jar:/home/gilles/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.android.tools.build/manifest-merger/31.4.0/c9b06c6a8b1dee31c38f723f572c8e2d40e29ac2/manifest-merger-31.4.0.jar:/home/gilles/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.android.tools/sdk-common/31.4.0/97562d4d24cf4d5dfa9b8a8dbb6d398cb58ba12e/sdk-common-31.4.0.jar:/home/gilles/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.android.tools/sdklib/31.4.0/a46cf34c0e396e335af15e2b6a2e907c69df7353/sdklib-31.4.0.jar:/home/gilles/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.android.tools/repository/31.4.0/f9d998909029644e8f7cf78cd850138ecf7cfcfd/repository-31.4.0.jar:/home/gilles/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.android.tools.build/aaptcompiler/8.4.0/5f732fe633f7f425930f1f187fd343813698fb0a/aaptcompiler-8.4.0.jar:/home/gilles/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.android.tools.analytics-library/tracker/31.4.0/369d37e578f8468b035ae74190aee44c9c05622c/tracker-31.4.0.jar:/home/gilles/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.android.tools.analytics-library/shared/31.4.0/58d6b88d63a1a3cb245ff761a36825864d037e56/shared-31.4.0.jar:/home/gilles/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/androidx.databinding/databinding-compiler-common/8.4.0/e86fdbcf76bd759987679928b50b9b442315e509/databinding-compiler-common-8.4.0.jar:/home/gilles/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.android.tools.utp/android-test-plugin-host-emulator-control-proto/31.4.0/faaddb0258a839e6ab89fe2acbe20ce29b403b43/android-test-plugin-host-emulator-control-proto-31.4.0.jar:/home/gilles/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.android.tools.utp/android-test-plugin-host-retention-proto/31.4.0/8ef946d4477f3b40b3bcb7d151131483b6d77d67/android-test-plugin-host-retention-proto-31.4.0.jar:/home/gilles/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.android.tools.build/builder-model/8.4.0/2ce5cd3c4157436ca795b20b26580bf6d932758d/builder-model-8.4.0.jar:/home/gilles/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.android.tools.build/gradle-api/8.4.0/715a2e42e17d2a0d3a7260fd6a988e6cf9574bf4/gradle-api-8.4.0.jar:/home/gilles/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.android.tools.build/builder-test-api/8.4.0/e49d832c8f2d4a769c19df8016572d30c756dd9c/builder-test-api-8.4.0.jar:/home/gilles/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.android.tools.ddms/ddmlib/31.4.0/91475e4672ba7fb06db00eb6638125611caa781c/ddmlib-31.4.0.jar:/home/gilles/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.android.tools.layoutlib/layoutlib-api/31.4.0/5b4270989aafbce80f83599e345afd927cf6ba26/layoutlib-api-31.4.0.jar:/home/gilles/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.android.tools/dvlib/31.4.0/4a640f3e66a0aa81ea193cb4a2e8fb10b4df3c9/dvlib-31.4.0.jar:/home/gilles/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.android.tools/common/31.4.0/b26bbba5cae63eb14426ceef78f4bed8837d9231/common-31.4.0.jar:/home/gilles/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-stdlib-jdk8/1.9.20/e2b4d1f475ae0606d063a84fce4dccdb45c7e12a/kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.9.20.jar:/home/gilles/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.android.tools.build.jetifier/jetifier-processor/1.0.0-beta10/946c39eb0c052ff4f60a8939648a8b99af20d604/jetifier-processor-1.0.0-beta10.jar:/home/gilles/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.android.tools.build.jetifier/jetifier-core/1.0.0-beta10/6e621022a9c95af12a7004d6b55805bbd1126837/jetifier-core-1.0.0-beta10.jar:/home/gilles/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-reflect/1.9.20/34eeb4eed5f493cdbb760ef50a5653ec414006bf/kotlin-reflect-1.9.20.jar:/home/gilles/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-stdlib-jdk7/1.9.20/8b4b73f4e08efaae93fc01d8c6eaab58a72d2ab3/kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.9.20.jar:/home/gilles/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-stdlib/1.9.20/e58b4816ac517e9cc5df1db051120c63d4cde669/kotlin-stdlib-1.9.20.jar:/home/gilles/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains/annotations/13.0/919f0dfe192fb4e063e7dacadee7f8bb9a2672a9/annotations-13.0.jar:/home/gilles/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.android.tools.build/bundletool/1.15.6/d804e9cf5387426500061a8e0eb5602d50a49e56/bundletool-1.15.6.jar:/home/gilles/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.android.tools.build/aapt2-proto/8.4.0-11315950/d0b137e4b167fa759062c4dd72f9d7f26c3470a1/aapt2-proto-8.4.0-11315950.jar:/home/gilles/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.android.tools.analytics-library/crash/31.4.0/669e0dbea9c0612c1752365738497bea9627a6b9/crash-31.4.0.jar:/home/gilles/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.android.tools.lint/lint-typedef-remover/31.4.0/644ab9b8a697ba83702c4e32eaaf95c504e1a522/lint-typedef-remover-31.4.0.jar:/home/gilles/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/androidx.databinding/databinding-common/8.4.0/2be3530b78477835e69dce953b17adc1dbc5c6fa/databinding-common-8.4.0.jar:/home/gilles/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.android.databinding/baseLibrary/8.4.0/7e7399239e52d4069896277615e005add7ae8e5a/baseLibrary-8.4.0.jar:/home/gilles/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.android.tools.utp/android-device-provider-ddmlib-proto/31.4.0/732647a1df2d9405dbbc944ccb1a9153d7dc3e3a/android-device-provider-ddmlib-proto-31.4.0.jar:/home/gilles/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.android.tools.utp/android-device-provider-gradle-proto/31.4.0/9f4923a6c0e213f00c1cc31720d1535f2d8517fe/android-device-provider-gradle-proto-31.4.0.jar:/home/gilles/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.android.tools.utp/android-test-plugin-host-additional-test-output-proto/31.4.0/c02332c53d95a3e0ccd7ad9d6d97f8fec5d1a469/android-test-plugin-host-additional-test-output-proto-31.4.0.jar:/home/gilles/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.android.tools.utp/android-test-plugin-host-coverage-proto/31.4.0/c780344aab70a33c454ad697295e12278fed16db/android-test-plugin-host-coverage-proto-31.4.0.jar:/home/gilles/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.android.tools.utp/android-test-plugin-host-logcat-proto/31.4.0/d8f873c14c5c65746b97801c2c6cae506d0b3d29/android-test-plugin-host-logcat-proto-31.4.0.jar:/home/gilles/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.android.tools.utp/android-test-plugin-host-apk-installer-proto/31.4.0/eab0d04ab0181f625bd2c22a800ccc12d6e555c/android-test-plugin-host-apk-installer-proto-31.4.0.jar:/home/gilles/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.android.tools.utp/android-test-plugin-result-listener-gradle-proto/31.4.0/f51d5e35aa252438265500d79fc2d314b7555b94/android-test-plugin-result-listener-gradle-proto-31.4.0.jar:/home/gilles/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.android.tools.build/transform-api/2.0.0-deprecated-use-gradle-api/47f6c56527c42425742fa9b56ffd3fd80763fe03/transform-api-2.0.0-deprecated-use-gradle-api.jar:/home/gilles/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.apache.httpcomponents/httpmime/4.5.6/164343da11db817e81e24e0d9869527e069850c9/httpmime-4.5.6.jar:/home/gilles/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/commons-io/commons-io/2.13.0/8bb2bc9b4df17e2411533a0708a69f983bf5e83b/commons-io-2.13.0.jar:/home/gilles/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.ow2.asm/asm-commons/9.6/f1a9e5508eff490744144565c47326c8648be309/asm-commons-9.6.jar:/home/gilles/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.ow2.asm/asm-util/9.6/f77caf84eb93786a749b2baa40865b9613e3eaee/asm-util-9.6.jar:/home/gilles/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.ow2.asm/asm-analysis/9.6/9ce6c7b174bd997fc2552dff47964546bd7a5ec3/asm-analysis-9.6.jar:/home/gilles/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.ow2.asm/asm-tree/9.6/c0cdda9d211e965d2a4448aa3fd86110f2f8c2de/asm-tree-9.6.jar:/home/gilles/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.ow2.asm/asm/9.6/aa205cf0a06dbd8e04ece91c0b37c3f5d567546a/asm-9.6.jar:/home/gilles/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.android.tools.build/apkzlib/8.4.0/d656b52facbb301b8bdc1e40a5ae008bcf335fe9/apkzlib-8.4.0.jar:/home/gilles/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.bouncycastle/bcpkix-jdk18on/1.77/ed953791ba0229747dd0fd9911e3d76a462acfd3/bcpkix-jdk18on-1.77.jar:/home/gilles/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.glassfish.jaxb/jaxb-runtime/2.3.2/5528bc882ea499a09d720b42af11785c4fc6be2a/jaxb-runtime-2.3.2.jar:/home/gilles/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/net.sf.jopt-simple/jopt-simple/4.9/ee9e9eaa0a35360dcfeac129ff4923215fd65904/jopt-simple-4.9.jar:/home/gilles/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.squareup/javapoet/1.10.0/712c178d35185d8261295913c9f2a7d6867a6007/javapoet-1.10.0.jar:/home/gilles/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.google.protobuf/protobuf-java-util/3.22.3/749cd4fe8ab52f37bc186193802ba19f5b284647/protobuf-java-util-3.22.3.jar:/home/gilles/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/io.grpc/grpc-protobuf/1.57.0/49986e40de6cbd14ba26247639b18ab0bac921c1/grpc-protobuf-1.57.0.jar:/home/gilles/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.google.crypto.tink/tink/1.7.0/668b57f109d32349b2870448f06ae6f202713edc/tink-1.7.0.jar:/home/gilles/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.android.tools.analytics-library/protos/31.4.0/4d9390bf76e306bb6560ac7ac5589969281124db/protos-31.4.0.jar:/home/gilles/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.google.api.grpc/proto-google-common-protos/2.17.0/7edf1e3aa96dc3861f7a8f24556c714e9c5b292/proto-google-common-protos-2.17.0.jar:/home/gilles/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.google.protobuf/protobuf-java/3.22.3/fdee98b8f6abab73f146a4edb4c09e56f8278d03/protobuf-java-3.22.3.jar:/home/gilles/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/io.grpc/grpc-netty/1.57.0/99cc01516c2fd1d134bf2585c2b38fa400804986/grpc-netty-1.57.0.jar:/home/gilles/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/io.grpc/grpc-core/1.57.0/2b6ef5166f31315098fff9bb85f33ab5fed58f6b/grpc-core-1.57.0.jar:/home/gilles/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.google.code.gson/gson/2.10.1/b3add478d4382b78ea20b1671390a858002feb6c/gson-2.10.1.jar:/home/gilles/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/io.grpc/grpc-stub/1.57.0/262e1469c080164d5e2459f4908394d66f4e8828/grpc-stub-1.57.0.jar:/home/gilles/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.google.testing.platform/core-proto/0.0.9-alpha02/ee54219cbb4a7fb83cdc528e9a85e0383f3ee726/core-proto-0.0.9-alpha02.jar:/home/gilles/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/net.sf.kxml/kxml2/2.3.0/ccbc77a5fd907ef863c29f3596c6f54ffa4e9442/kxml2-2.3.0.jar:/home/gilles/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.tensorflow/tensorflow-lite-metadata/0.1.0-rc2/7aa9b3e16d85c2aae5eff741265315a37c9f731a/tensorflow-lite-metadata-0.1.0-rc2.jar:/home/gilles/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.google.flatbuffers/flatbuffers-java/1.12.0/8201cc7b511177a37071249e891f2f2fea4b32e9/flatbuffers-java-1.12.0.jar:/home/gilles/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.google.jimfs/jimfs/1.1/8fbd0579dc68aba6186935cc1bee21d2f3e7ec1c/jimfs-1.1.jar:/home/gilles/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/io.grpc/grpc-context/1.57.0/8d8f26a9b0bed637ee4592e1df3ef134ed2c54fd/grpc-context-1.57.0.jar:/home/gilles/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/io.grpc/grpc-protobuf-lite/1.57.0/ca0084219b71d29cd9bfc3b81780aca91a965753/grpc-protobuf-lite-1.57.0.jar:/home/gilles/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/io.grpc/grpc-api/1.57.0/768ab3e583b213a3672ec776e70765b594e8bbe5/grpc-api-1.57.0.jar:/home/gilles/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.google.guava/guava/32.0.1-jre/6e5d51a72d142f2d40a57dfb897188b36a95b489/guava-32.0.1-jre.jar:/home/gilles/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.google.dagger/dagger/2.28.3/10d83810ef9e19714116ed518896c90c6606d633/dagger-2.28.3.jar:/home/gilles/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/javax.inject/javax.inject/1/6975da39a7040257bd51d21a231b76c915872d38/javax.inject-1.jar:/home/gilles/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.bouncycastle/bcutil-jdk18on/1.77/de3eaef351545fe8562cf29ddff4a403a45b49b7/bcutil-jdk18on-1.77.jar:/home/gilles/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.bouncycastle/bcprov-jdk18on/1.77/2cc971b6c20949c1ff98d1a4bc741ee848a09523/bcprov-jdk18on-1.77.jar:/home/gilles/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.intellij.deps/trove4j/1.0.20200330/3afb14d5f9ceb459d724e907a21145e8ff394f02/trove4j-1.0.20200330.jar:/home/gilles/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.apache.commons/commons-compress/1.21/4ec95b60d4e86b5c95a0e919cb172a0af98011ef/commons-compress-1.21.jar:/home/gilles/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.apache.httpcomponents/httpclient/4.5.14/1194890e6f56ec29177673f2f12d0b8e627dec98/httpclient-4.5.14.jar:/home/gilles/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.apache.httpcomponents/httpcore/4.4.16/51cf043c87253c9f58b539c9f7e44c8894223850/httpcore-4.4.16.jar:/home/gilles/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.sun.activation/javax.activation/1.2.0/bf744c1e2776ed1de3c55c8dac1057ec331ef744/javax.activation-1.2.0.jar:/home/gilles/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.android/signflinger/8.4.0/13f035dd8e7e470ff8f3216a0b46333187f26df5/signflinger-8.4.0.jar:/home/gilles/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.android/zipflinger/8.4.0/de8e3267995699af356740cf562cbedb485f5763/zipflinger-8.4.0.jar:/home/gilles/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.android.tools/annotations/31.4.0/7f3cdb30f22d5cf7878c1c4b0e40dbcc71112331/annotations-31.4.0.jar:/home/gilles/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/net.java.dev.jna/jna-platform/5.6.0/d18424ffb8bbfd036d71bcaab9b546858f2ef986/jna-platform-5.6.0.jar:/home/gilles/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.googlecode.juniversalchardet/juniversalchardet/1.0.3/cd49678784c46aa8789c060538e0154013bb421b/juniversalchardet-1.0.3.jar:/home/gilles/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/javax.annotation/javax.annotation-api/1.3.2/934c04d3cfef185a8008e7bf34331b79730a9d43/javax.annotation-api-1.3.2.jar:/home/gilles/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jvnet.staxex/stax-ex/1.8.1/78011e483a21102fb4858f3e8f269a677e50aa23/stax-ex-1.8.1.jar:/home/gilles/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/jakarta.xml.bind/jakarta.xml.bind-api/2.3.2/8d49996a4338670764d7ca4b85a1c4ccf7fe665d/jakarta.xml.bind-api-2.3.2.jar:/home/gilles/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.glassfish.jaxb/txw2/2.3.2/ce5be7da2e442c25ec14c766cb60cb802741727b/txw2-2.3.2.jar:/home/gilles/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.sun.istack/istack-commons-runtime/3.0.8/d6a97364045aa6b99bf2d3c566a3f98599c2d296/istack-commons-runtime-3.0.8.jar:/home/gilles/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.sun.xml.fastinfoset/FastInfoset/1.2.16/4eb6a0adad553bf759ffe86927df6f3b848c8bea/FastInfoset-1.2.16.jar:/home/gilles/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/jakarta.activation/jakarta.activation-api/1.2.1/562a587face36ec7eff2db7f2fc95425c6602bc1/jakarta.activation-api-1.2.1.jar:/home/gilles/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.google.auto.value/auto-value-annotations/1.6.2/ed193d86e0af90cc2342aedbe73c5d86b03fa09b/auto-value-annotations-1.6.2.jar:/home/gilles/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.google.errorprone/error_prone_annotations/2.18.0/89b684257096f548fa39a7df9fdaa409d4d4df91/error_prone_annotations-2.18.0.jar:/home/gilles/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.bitbucket.b_c/jose4j/0.7.0/478ee8518687f9b01f20912fc7edd9d7b46d06da/jose4j-0.7.0.jar:/home/gilles/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.slf4j/slf4j-api/1.7.30/b5a4b6d16ab13e34a88fae84c35cd5d68cac922c/slf4j-api-1.7.30.jar:/home/gilles/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jdom/jdom2/2.0.6/6f14738ec2e9dd0011e343717fa624a10f8aab64/jdom2-2.0.6.jar:/home/gilles/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.google.code.findbugs/jsr305/3.0.2/25ea2e8b0c338a877313bd4672d3fe056ea78f0d/jsr305-3.0.2.jar:/home/gilles/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.google.j2objc/j2objc-annotations/2.8/c85270e307e7b822f1086b93689124b89768e273/j2objc-annotations-2.8.jar:/home/gilles/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.google.android/annotations/4.1.1.4/a1678ba907bf92691d879fef34e1a187038f9259/annotations-4.1.1.4.jar:/home/gilles/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.codehaus.mojo/animal-sniffer-annotations/1.23/3c0daebd5f0e1ce72cc50c818321ac957aeb5d70/animal-sniffer-annotations-1.23.jar:/home/gilles/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/io.perfmark/perfmark-api/0.26.0/ef65452adaf20bf7d12ef55913aba24037b82738/perfmark-api-0.26.0.jar:/home/gilles/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/io.netty/netty-codec-http2/4.1.93.Final/f1625b43bde13ec057da0d2fe381ded2547a70e/netty-codec-http2-4.1.93.Final.jar:/home/gilles/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/io.netty/netty-handler-proxy/4.1.93.Final/c165c1efe1b9c0cc22546a057b530611a088768b/netty-handler-proxy-4.1.93.Final.jar:/home/gilles/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/io.netty/netty-codec-http/4.1.93.Final/36acf0c94d03eb6ecef78a749a32cbb7dc0c57b4/netty-codec-http-4.1.93.Final.jar:/home/gilles/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/io.netty/netty-handler/4.1.93.Final/10f7ed9d8e1bfcba416074c70e5388be96116bfc/netty-handler-4.1.93.Final.jar:/home/gilles/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/io.netty/netty-transport-native-unix-common/4.1.93.Final/f4fb8b4c8da539091f43abcbb9f0389e48807eea/netty-transport-native-unix-common-4.1.93.Final.jar:/home/gilles/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.checkerframework/checker-qual/3.33.0/de2b60b62da487644fc11f734e73c8b0b431238f/checker-qual-3.33.0.jar:/home/gilles/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/commons-codec/commons-codec/1.11/3acb4705652e16236558f0f4f2192cc33c3bd189/commons-codec-1.11.jar:/home/gilles/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.android.tools.build/apksig/8.4.0/d51ecbc4a5b7a2c7832586a4dde18f61d92810a4/apksig-8.4.0.jar:/home/gilles/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.squareup/javawriter/2.5.0/81241ff7078ef14f42ea2a8995fa09c096256e6b/javawriter-2.5.0.jar:/home/gilles/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.google.guava/failureaccess/1.0.1/1dcf1de382a0bf95a3d8b0849546c88bac1292c9/failureaccess-1.0.1.jar:/home/gilles/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.google.guava/listenablefuture/9999.0-empty-to-avoid-conflict-with-guava/b421526c5f297295adef1c886e5246c39d4ac629/listenablefuture-9999.0-empty-to-avoid-conflict-with-guava.jar:/home/gilles/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/commons-logging/commons-logging/1.2/4bfc12adfe4842bf07b657f0369c4cb522955686/commons-logging-1.2.jar:/home/gilles/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/net.java.dev.jna/jna/5.6.0/330f2244e9030119ab3030fc3fededc86713d9cc/jna-5.6.0.jar:/home/gilles/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/io.netty/netty-codec-socks/4.1.93.Final/81ca78969afc60073e47c3b7b361cc3839392c73/netty-codec-socks-4.1.93.Final.jar:/home/gilles/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/io.netty/netty-codec/4.1.93.Final/503badb458b6586632be8d1f81aa4e5ab99a80fc/netty-codec-4.1.93.Final.jar:/home/gilles/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/io.netty/netty-transport/4.1.93.Final/1a0894915c8027ce83b4d6a811c4e765955efd15/netty-transport-4.1.93.Final.jar:/home/gilles/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/io.netty/netty-buffer/4.1.93.Final/87fac21f4ef95157866b07b48e3c707a2f13c581/netty-buffer-4.1.93.Final.jar:/home/gilles/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/io.netty/netty-resolver/4.1.93.Final/3860e99075f9e078364ed38f6d6fc8825b7a168a/netty-resolver-4.1.93.Final.jar:/home/gilles/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/io.netty/netty-common/4.1.93.Final/1cfc49b91b0d3ddb30c9f7d8467e5d02ae8babdf/netty-common-4.1.93.Final.jar:/home/gilles/AndroidStudioProjects/App9/.gradle/8.6/dependencies-accessors/19666b7ee7477488faba75fa6199859f9eeb0a35/classes:/home/gilles/.gradle/caches/8.6/kotlin-dsl/accessors/83d5d4ef8c14e1310b36236d8321f0d6/classes:/home/gilles/.gradle/caches/8.6/kotlin-dsl/accessors/4471bb54d85a684abaceab28e52bc96a-VC/classes:/home/gilles/.gradle/caches/8.6/kotlin-dsl/accessors/4471bb54d85a684abaceab28e52bc96a-PS/classes:/home/gilles/.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-8.6-bin/afr5mpiioh2wthjmwnkmdsd5w/gradle-8.6/lib/gradle-core-api-8.6.jar:/home/gilles/.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-8.6-bin/afr5mpiioh2wthjmwnkmdsd5w/gradle-8.6/lib/gradle-core-8.6.jar org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.K2JVMCompiler -kotlin-home /home/gilles/android-studio/plugins/Kotlin/kotlinc -script /home/gilles/AndroidStudioProjects/App9/app/build.gradle.kts



build.gradle.kts:1:1: error: unresolved reference: plugins
plugins {
^
build.gradle.kts:2:5: error: unresolved reference: alias
    alias(libs.plugins.android.application)
    ^
build.gradle.kts:2:11: error: unresolved reference: libs
    alias(libs.plugins.android.application)
          ^
build.gradle.kts:5:1: error: unresolved reference: android
android {
^
build.gradle.kts:6:5: error: unresolved reference: namespace
    namespace = "fr.albisys.app9"
    ^
build.gradle.kts:7:5: error: unresolved reference: compileSdk
    compileSdk = 34
    ^
build.gradle.kts:9:5: error: unresolved reference: defaultConfig
    defaultConfig {
    ^
build.gradle.kts:10:9: error: unresolved reference: applicationId
        applicationId = "fr.albisys.app9"
        ^
build.gradle.kts:11:9: error: unresolved reference: minSdk
        minSdk = 24
        ^
build.gradle.kts:12:9: error: unresolved reference: targetSdk
        targetSdk = 34
        ^
build.gradle.kts:13:9: error: unresolved reference: versionCode
        versionCode = 1
        ^
build.gradle.kts:14:9: error: unresolved reference: versionName
        versionName = "1.0"
        ^
build.gradle.kts:16:9: error: unresolved reference: testInstrumentationRunner
        testInstrumentationRunner = "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        ^
build.gradle.kts:19:5: error: unresolved reference: buildTypes
    buildTypes {
    ^
build.gradle.kts:20:9: error: unresolved reference: release
        release {
        ^
build.gradle.kts:21:13: error: unresolved reference: isMinifyEnabled
            isMinifyEnabled = false
            ^
build.gradle.kts:22:13: error: unresolved reference: proguardFiles
            proguardFiles(getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android-optimize.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro")
            ^
build.gradle.kts:22:27: error: unresolved reference: getDefaultProguardFile
            proguardFiles(getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android-optimize.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro")
                          ^
build.gradle.kts:25:5: error: unresolved reference: compileOptions
    compileOptions {
    ^
build.gradle.kts:26:9: error: unresolved reference: sourceCompatibility
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        ^
build.gradle.kts:26:31: error: unresolved reference: JavaVersion
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
                              ^
build.gradle.kts:27:9: error: unresolved reference: targetCompatibility
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        ^
build.gradle.kts:27:31: error: unresolved reference: JavaVersion
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
                              ^
build.gradle.kts:29:5: error: unresolved reference: buildFeatures
    buildFeatures {
    ^
build.gradle.kts:30:9: error: unresolved reference: viewBinding
        viewBinding = true
        ^
build.gradle.kts:34:1: error: unresolved reference: dependencies
dependencies {
^
build.gradle.kts:36:5: error: unresolved reference: implementation
    implementation(libs.appcompat)
    ^
build.gradle.kts:36:20: error: unresolved reference: libs
    implementation(libs.appcompat)
                   ^
build.gradle.kts:37:5: error: unresolved reference: implementation
    implementation(libs.material)
    ^
build.gradle.kts:37:20: error: unresolved reference: libs
    implementation(libs.material)
                   ^
build.gradle.kts:38:5: error: unresolved reference: implementation
    implementation(libs.activity)
    ^
build.gradle.kts:38:20: error: unresolved reference: libs
    implementation(libs.activity)
                   ^
build.gradle.kts:39:5: error: unresolved reference: implementation
    implementation(libs.constraintlayout)
    ^
build.gradle.kts:39:20: error: unresolved reference: libs
    implementation(libs.constraintlayout)
                   ^
build.gradle.kts:40:5: error: unresolved reference: testImplementation
    testImplementation(libs.junit)
    ^
build.gradle.kts:40:24: error: unresolved reference: libs
    testImplementation(libs.junit)
                       ^
build.gradle.kts:41:5: error: unresolved reference: androidTestImplementation
    androidTestImplementation(libs.ext.junit)
    ^
build.gradle.kts:41:31: error: unresolved reference: libs
    androidTestImplementation(libs.ext.junit)
                              ^
build.gradle.kts:42:5: error: unresolved reference: androidTestImplementation
    androidTestImplementation(libs.espresso.core)
    ^
build.gradle.kts:42:31: error: unresolved reference: libs
    androidTestImplementation(libs.espresso.core)
                          ^

Process finished with exit code 1

From @Nadine Bensefia: does appear the same error whene click sync gradle?

try to change in build.gradle (project) min sdk 24 and target sdk 33

That what I did initially and with min sdk 31. And that is when I started to fail at compiling build.gradle
